# Gatsby ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT not working as intended

Tags: reactjs, node.js, wordpress, gatsby, .env

I am building with Gatsby for the frontend and wordpress for headless CMS. when I make a change on my wordpress post, i want the change to reflect in my gatsby page instantly. however, when i make a change, i have to stop and restart the server for the changes to reflect. I have looked through gatsby documentation and added "ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT" to my env file but it is not working. What am i doing wrongly?
Here is the content in my .env at the root of my project directory

```
ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT=true
```

here is my gatsby-config file

```
import type { GatsbyConfig } from 'gatsby'
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv' // see https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#how-do-i-use-dotenv-with-import
dotenv.config()


const config: GatsbyConfig = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: meta.title,
    description: meta.description,
    siteUrl: meta.siteUrl,
    logo: meta.logo,
  },
  // More easily incorporate content into your pages through automatic TypeScript type generation and better GraphQL IntelliSense.
  // If you use VSCode you can also use the GraphQL plugin
  // Learn more at: https://gatsby.dev/graphql-typegen
  graphqlTypegen: true,
  plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-postcss',
    'gatsby-plugin-image',
    'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
      options: {
        url:
          // allows a fallback url if WPGRAPHQL_URL is not set in the env, this may be a local or remote WP instance.

          `http://url/graphql`,
        schema: {
          //Prefixes all WP Types with "Wp" so "Post and allPost" become "WpPost and allWpPost".
          typePrefix: `Wp`,
          timeout: 3000000,
        },
        develop: {
          //caches media files outside of Gatsby's default cache an thus allows them to persist through a cache reset.
          hardCacheMediaFiles: true,
        },
        type: {
          Post: {
            limit:
              process.env.NODE_ENV === `development`
                ? // Lets just pull 50 posts in development to make it easy on ourselves (aka. faster).
                  50
                : // and we don't actually need more than 5000 in production for this particular site
                  5000,
          },
          Page: {
            limit: 0,
          },

          MenuItem: {
            limit: 0,
          },

          User: {
            limit: 0,
          },
          Tag: {
            limit: 0,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        icon: 'src/images/logo.png',
      },
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-sitemap',
      options: {
        exclude: ['/thankyou'],
      },
    },
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: './src/images/',
      },
      __key: 'images',
    },
    'gatsby-plugin-react-svg',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-manifest',
      options: {
        name: meta.title,
        short_name: meta.title,
        start_url: '/',
        background_color: 'white',
        theme_color: '#101C45',
        display: 'standalone',
        lang: 'en',
        icon: 'static/logo.png',
        description: meta.description,
      },
    },
  ],
}

export default config
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `ENABLE_GATSBY_REFRESH_ENDPOINT` to `true` in your environment you are enabling a webhook which can be triggered to refresh your site.

To test this out, run a local development version of the site, setting the environment variable. Then trigger a refresh by hitting the webhook:

```bash
curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/__refresh
```

You should see that pages are rebuilt.

More details about this can be found [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/refreshing-content/).

Now you need to set up a trigger on your Wordpress site which will hit the corresponding webhook on your deployed Gatsby site. See [this](https://wordpress.com/support/webhooks/) for details on how this would be done.

There's a blog post [here](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2024/01/wordpress-headless-cms/) which gives details on how you can set up a local testing environment for webhooks with Gatsby and Wordpress.